# What is the Kerr factor for Sagittarius A*?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, kerr-metric

I have searched for it, but everything what I [found](http://www.scilogs.de/einsteins-kosmos/das-n-chste-schwarze-loch-zur-erde/) is that A0620-00 (the current closest black-hole to Earth) is a slow spinner with Kerr factor $a=0.12$.

How about the Kerr factor for [Sagittarius A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagittarius_A*)?

Answer (score 3):

With current technologies the Kerr parameter could not be precisely estimated yet.

The best result today is a Kerr factor $a=0.52$.

- Genzel, R., Schoedel, R., Ott, T., Eckart, A., Alexander, T., Lacombe, F., Rouan
  & Aschenbach, B., Near-infrared flares from accreting gas around the
  supermassive black hole at the Galactic Centre (2003), astro-ph/0310821

[History of BH's (in German)](http://www.wissenschaft-online.de/astrowissen/astro_sl_hist.html)

Better estimates are expected within the next two decades, according to the [article](http://www.wissenschaft-online.de/astrowissen/astro_sl_hist.html).